# No se imprimen los bordes de la tabla en TCPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

Al momento de ejecutar un reporte PDF desde `tcpdf` no presenta las lineas de la tabla aunque están igual como presentan los objetos en que parte debo cambiar para que se me presenten los bordes de la tabla.

```
    $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('JOSE LOOR');
    $pdf->SetTitle('RECIBO DE ENTREGA');
    $pdf->SetSubject('PEDIDO');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('SACI');
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

     // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }
     $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9, '', true);
     $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
    $pdf->Image('img/logo.png', 15, 10, 180, 35, 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $html = "<table border='1' align='center' style='text-align:center;' bordercolor='blue' cellspacing='0'>    
    <tr>
        <td width='150' >
        </td>
        <td>
          EUFRATESINVEST SA  
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>RUC:</b>  
        </td>
        <td>
            0992346531001
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>DIRECCION:</b> 
        </td>
        <td>
          KM 1 1/2 VIA LAS MERCEDES    
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>FACTURA</b>  
        </td>
        <td>
            No. 003002000004754
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <b>OBLIGADO A LLEVAR CONTABILIDAD</b>   
        </td>
        <td>
          SI
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            0992346531001
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
       <b>NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS</b>   
        </td>
        <td>
          LUIS QUIMBULCO
        </td>
        <td>
         <b>IDENTIFICACION</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            0992346531001
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <b>FECHA DE EMISION:</b>   
        </td>
        <td>
          12/12/2015
        </td>
        <td>
         </b>GUIA DE REMISION:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            0992346531001
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>";
  $header = array('CODIGO', 'DETALLE','CANTIDAD','PRECIO','TOTAL');
  $html=utf8_encode($html);
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, true, '');
  $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El soporte para HTML de TCPDF es muy sencillo (aunque sea mejor que FPDF): https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407

> Allows to preserve some HTML formatting (limited support).
>
> **IMPORTANT:** The HTML must be well formatted - try to clean-up it using an application like HTML-Tidy before submitting. Supported tags are: a, b, blockquote, br, dd, del, div, dl, dt, em, font, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, i, img, li, ol, p, pre, small, span, strong, sub, sup, table, tcpdf, td, th, thead, tr, tt, u, ul.
>
> **NOTE:** all the HTML attributes must be enclosed in double-quote.

Como puedes ver es un analizador de HTML muy básico programado dentro del código: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L17110

Deberías hacer uso de herramientas de creación de documentos más potentes (como DocBook) si necesitas la flexibilidad de crear tablas sin programar el código que genere una a una las celdas de la tabla que necesitas para cada registro.

Edito: Tal y como te recomienda el artículo, he limpiado tu HTML y he puesto los atributos con comillas dobles y ahora me genera el borde de la tabla correctamente:

```
<?php
$html = '<table border="1" align="center" bordercolor="blue" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="150"></td>
<td>EUFRATESINVEST SA</td>
<td>RUC:</td>
<td>0992346531001</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DIRECCION:</td>
<td>KM 1 1/2 VIA LAS MERCEDES</td>
<td>FACTURA</td>
<td>No. 003002000004754</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>OBLIGADO A LLEVAR CONTABILIDAD</td>
<td>SI</td>
<td></td>
<td>0992346531001</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS</td>
<td>LUIS QUIMBULCO</td>
<td>IDENTIFICACION</td>
<td>0992346531001</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>FECHA DE EMISION:</td>
<td>12/12/2015</td>
<td>GUIA DE REMISION:</td>
<td>0992346531001</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Te insisto en que el soporte para HTML es muy sencillo, por lo que es probable que no puedas pedirle demasiado. Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que veas esto: http://www.fpdf.org/es/tutorial/tuto5.htm
Es mejor que pasar fragmentos html

Comment: Está usando `TCPDF` y no `FPDF`. `FPDF`, como puse en mi respuesta, tiene un soporte muy básico de HTML, pero el de `TCPDF` es mucho mejor: soporta más etiquetas y más atributos (bordes, colores de fondo, etc). Por otro lado, procura agregar a tu respuesta la parte más relevante del contenido del enlace al que haces referencia. Gracias por tu aporte :)